# Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I need to make onetomany relationship but this error appears
mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property
this is parent `Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property`

```
package com.dating.model;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType; 
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
@Entity
@Table(name="question")
public class PsyQuestions {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name="autoGen" ,strategy="increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="autoGen")
    @Column(name="questionid")
    private long psyQuestionId;
    @Column(name="questiontext")
    private String question;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="question")
    private List<PsyOptions> productlist=new ArrayList<PsyOptions>();


    public PsyQuestions() {
        super();
    }

    public List<PsyOptions> getProductlist() {
        return productlist;
    }

    public void setProductlist(List<PsyOptions> productlist) {
        this.productlist = productlist;
    }

    public long getPsyQuestionId() {
        return psyQuestionId;
    }
    public void setPsyQuestionId(long psyQuestionId) {
        this.psyQuestionId = psyQuestionId;
    }
    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }
    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }
}
```

and this child class

```
package com.dating.model;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

@Entity
@Table(name="option")
public class PsyOptions {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name="autoGen" ,strategy="increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="autoGen")
    @Column(name="optionid")
    private long psyOptionId;
    @Column(name="optiontext")
    private String optionText;

    @JoinColumn(name = "questionid")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    PsyQuestions psyQuestions;  


    public PsyOptions() {
        super();
    }

    public PsyQuestions getPsyQuestions() {
        return psyQuestions;
    }

    public void setPsyQuestions(PsyQuestions psyQuestions) {
        this.psyQuestions = psyQuestions;
    }

    public long getPsyOptionId() {
        return psyOptionId;
    }
    public void setPsyOptionId(long psyOptionId) {
        this.psyOptionId = psyOptionId;
    }
    public String getOptionText() {
        return optionText;
    }
    public void setOptionText(String optionText) {
        this.optionText = optionText;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to set the `mappedBy` attribute of the `@OneToMany` annotation to **psyQuestions** instead of **question**. The value of `mappedBy` attributes is the name of the class field on the other side of the relationship, in this case **psyQuestions** of the `ManyToOne` side of class PsyOptions.

```
public class PsyQuestions {
....
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="psyQuestions")
private List<PsyOptions> productlist=new ArrayList<PsyOptions>();
....
```

Comment: mappedBy attribute already set for psyQuestions entity which map to question table

Comment: @AliAliAbdelFatah the code you have posted shows `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="question")`. This has to change as mentioned in answer.

Comment: thank you so much  it's solved my error is put name of table  in mappedBy attribute

Comment: @AliAliAbdelFatah please don't forget to accept the answer, to assist other visitors as well, thanks

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue because the mappedBy in the source entity was defined to "enrollment" (annotated with @OneToMany) but the corresponding property in the target entity was "bankEnrollment"; this is the property annotated with @ManyToOne.

After updating from enrollment to bankEnrollmentin the source entity, the exception went away (as expected_.

Lesson learnt: the mappedBy value (e.g. psyQuestions) should exist as a property name in the target entity.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is going to help anyone, it was a simple mistake caused this error on my config. Without realising I have had two different packages containing domain class files. Mapped member was in the other package while the application was only scanning single package path.

It was hard to figure out as they were different only by a single character e.g. org.abc.core.domains and org.abcs.core.domains.

Added other package to database @configuration scanners resolved the issue for me.

Comment: I solved the problem with this annotation `@ComponentScan({"com.dating.model"})`

Answer (score 0):

I just correct my mapping and it solved the problem.

```
...
     @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="question")
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This error typically occurs when there is a mismatch between the property name specified in the "mappedBy" attribute of a Hibernate mapping annotation and the actual property name in the target entity.

Here's an example of how this error might occur:

Suppose you have two entities: "Order" and "OrderLineItem", and you want to map a one-to-many relationship from Order to OrderLineItem. You might define the mapping on the Order entity as follows:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="order")
private List<OrderLineItem> lineItems;
```

In this mapping, the "mappedBy" attribute specifies that the "order"
property in the OrderLineItem entity is the inverse side of the relationship.

Now suppose that there is a typo in the property name specified in the mappedBy attribute, like this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="orders")
private List<OrderLineItem> lineItems;
```

In this case, Hibernate will not be able to find the "orders" property in the OrderLineItem entity, and it will throw the "mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property" error.

To fix this error, you should double-check that the property name specified in the mappedBy attribute matches the actual property name in the target entity.