# JPA Issues @OneToMany(MappedBy)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have this issue with these models in my project and I don't know what is the issue exactly with these two models and these two realationships in Data JPA Car Model Below:

```
package com.wq.v1.domain.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "cars")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Car implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="firm_id", nullable=false)
    private Firm firm;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "driver_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Driver driver;

    @Column(name = "car_type")
    private String car_type;

    @Column(name = "car_model")
    private String car_model;

    @Column(name = "car_plate")
    private String car_plate;

    @Column(name = "car_owner")
    private String car_owner;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="cars")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Image> images;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="cars")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Docs> docs;

    public Car(){

    }

    public Car(Firm firm, Driver driver, String car_type, String car_model, String car_plate, String car_owner, Set<Image> images, Set<Docs> docs) {
        this.firm = firm;
        this.driver = driver;
        this.car_type = car_type;
        this.car_model = car_model;
        this.car_plate = car_plate;
        this.car_owner = car_owner;
        this.images = images;
        this.docs = docs;
    }
}
```

And this is the Docs model:

```
package com.wq.v1.domain.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "docs")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Docs implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "driver_id", nullable = false)
    private Driver driver;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="car_id", nullable=false)
    private Car car;

    @Column(name = "nat_id", columnDefinition = "LONGTEXT")
    private String nat_id;

    @Column(name = "passport", columnDefinition = "LONGTEXT")
    private String passport;

    @Column(name = "driver_license", columnDefinition = "LONGTEXT")
    private String driver_license;

    @Column(name = "resd_id", columnDefinition = "LONGTEXT")
    private String resd_id;

    @Column(name = "resd_permit", columnDefinition = "LONGTEXT")
    private String resd_permit;

    @Column(name = "car_register", columnDefinition = "LONGTEXT")
    private String car_register;

    @Column(name = "disclaim", columnDefinition = "LONGTEXT")
    private String disclaim;

    @Column(name = "trans_autho", columnDefinition = "LONGTEXT")
    private String trans_autho;

    public Docs(){

    }

    public Docs(Driver driver, Car car, String nat_id, String passport, String driver_license, String resd_id, String resd_permit, String car_register, String disclaim, String trans_autho) {
        this.driver = driver;
        this.car = car;
        this.nat_id = nat_id;
        this.passport = passport;
        this.driver_license = driver_license;
        this.resd_id = resd_id;
        this.resd_permit = resd_permit;
        this.car_register = car_register;
        this.disclaim = disclaim;
        this.trans_autho = trans_autho;
    }
}
```

And finally this is the error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.wq.v1.domain.model.Docs.cars in com.wq.v1.domain.model.Car.docs
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1159) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:588) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at com.wq.v1.V1Application.main(V1Application.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.wq.v1.domain.model.Docs.cars in com.wq.v1.domain.model.Car.docs
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:844) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:795) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:53) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1693) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1661) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:295) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1847) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    ... 22 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

I searched a lot a tried many ways to fix it and didn't work even here I found a lot of questions without solving in here.

Comment: Replace `mappedBy="cars"` above `Set <Docs> ...` with `mappedBy="car"`. *It says that there is no such definition in `Docs.class`.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20454945/caused-by-org-hibernate-annotationexception-mappedby-reference-an-unknown-targ)